# php mail не работает. Странное поведение функции

Tags: php

```html
 if( !empty($_POST['name1']) && !empty($_POST['phone1']) && !empty($_POST['comment1'])){
    $phone = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone1']));
    $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name1']));
    $comment = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment1']));
    $subject = "Обратный звонок";
    $message = "Имя:$name \r\n";
    $message.= "Номер телефона: $phone \r\n";
    $message.= "Комментарий: $comment";
   
    mail("вфв@fsk23.ru", $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plain; windows-1251");
```

так отправка не работает но если  добавить fwrite все становится замечательно

```html
 if( !empty($_POST['name1']) && !empty($_POST['phone1']) && !empty($_POST['comment1'])){
    $phone = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone1']));
    $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name1']));
    $comment = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment1']));
    $subject = "Обратный звонок";
    $message = "Имя:$name \r\n";
    $message.= "Номер телефона: $phone \r\n";
    $message.= "Комментарий: $comment";
    $fopen = fopen('hello.php','w+');
    fwrite($fopen,$message);
    fclose($fopen);
    mail("info@fsk23.ru", $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plain; windows-1251");
```

Comment: 1. Что за сервер - у вас дома, шаред, vds? 2. Буду полагать, что Linux. Тогда выполните `echo ini_get('sendmail_path');` и вывод сюда.  Скорее всего будет `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`. Тогда из командной строки bash: `file /usr/sbin/sendmail` и вывод сюда. 3. Сделайте скрипт в 2 строчки в вывод сюда `error_reporting(E_ALL); echo (int)mail('info@fsk23.ru', 'test', 'test');`

Comment: Платный хостинг. Hostinger.ru

Comment: Думаю, почтовый сервер уже настроен, но не факт. 1) зайдите сюда https://www.mail-tester.com/ и отправьте на этот ящик из своего скрипта письмо. Если не получите, то 2) Напишите результат действий из остальной части моего коммента: sendmail_path, file ..., (int)mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего ваша функция просто отключена на вашем хостинге. Напишите по этому поводу в тех-поддержеку, но вероятно там все подтвердят. Соотвественно именно вам эту функцию не включат, но в `PHP` Есть специальная библиотека которая несмотря на ваш сервер хостинг или что-либо, главное чтобы у вас был почтовый клиент, сможет отправлять почту. Библиотека называется `PHPMailer`, это объектно ориентированная библиотека, с отличной документацией.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы тестируете с локального сервера, то письма сохраняются в специальных деректориях, при этом вы можете настроить отправку и с локального сервера посредством `sendmail`.

Если тестируете на удаленном сервере (особенно бесплатном), то там возможно отключена функция `mail()`. Проверить это можно с помощью функции `phpinfo()`.